# Help in counting the number of distributions, the random assignment of $r=7$ balls to $n=7$ cells

Tags: probability, combinatorics, self-learning, balls-in-bins

I am a beginner in Probability Theory. Upon reading and solving few problems from the first five chapters from *Feller's - Introduction to Probability theory and applications* book, I know that, every counting problem is **abstractly equivalent** to **distributing $r$ balls to $n$ cells**.

Consider the case $r=7, n=7$. The number of distinguishable distributions are $7^7$.

The number of distinguishable distributions with the occupancy numbers $2,2,1,1,1,0,0$ appearing in any order is given by:

(1) Label the balls.

$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Selection} & \text{Distinguishable choices}\\
\hline
\text{Choose 2 balls to place in the first doubly occupied cell} & {7 \choose 2} \\
\text{Choose 2 balls to place in the second doubly occupied cell} & {5 \choose 2} \\
\text{Choose 1 ball to place in the first singly occupied cell} & {3 \choose 1} \\
\text{Choose 1 ball to place in the second singly occupied cell} & {2 \choose 1} \\
\text{Choose 1 ball to place in the third singly occupied cell} & {1 \choose 1} \\
\end{array}$

So, we've assigned $5$ labels to these balls (this is a $5$-tuple). This is just the multinomial coefficient $\frac{7!}{2!2!}$.
One such choice is $\{ab,cd,e,f,g\}$. The order of the sub-populations is important, so $\{ab,cd,e,f,g\}$ is distinguished from $\{cd,ab,e,f,g\}$. No attention is paid to the order within the groups.

(2) Label the cells.

$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Selection} & \text{Distinguishable choices}\\
\hline
\text{Choose 2 cells that will be doubly occupied} & {7 \choose 2} \\
\text{Choose 3 cells that will be singly occupied} & {5 \choose 3} \\
\text{Choose 2 empty cells} & {2 \choose 2} \\
\end{array}$

The number of distinguishable choices are $\frac{7!}{2!3!2!}$. This results in a $3$-tuple. One example would be $(12),(34),(567)$.

Now, when we multiply these quantities, to find the total number of distributions; it is simply like multiplying $2$ shirts with $3$ ties to get $2 \times 3 = 6$ shirt-tie pairs that can be worn on two consecutive days.

**Question.**

Since, $(12),(34),(567)$ is equivalent to  $(21),(34),(567)$, my understanding is: in the above product, we don't distinguish between $\vert ab \vert cd \vert e \vert f \vert g \vert \vert  \vert$ and $\vert cd \vert ab \vert e \vert f \vert g \vert \vert  \vert$ - they count as a single choice. And it is so, because the occupancy numbers are the same; switching the two's in $2,2,1,1,1,0,0$ does not change the outer appearance of the configuration?

Comment: Your reasoning in the example you cited is correct.  You first chose which balls would be paired and which would not be paired, then assigned the pairs and singletons to cells.  If I understand your question correctly, before the pairs and singletons are assigned to cells, what matters is which balls are paired, not the order in which we pair them.